# How DO I write a SQL query to show related records in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an SQL Server query that will list the select rows from the first table and list the related records from the second table on the same row as the first table record.

Here is the dataset from the first table

```
 tblName
 NID    Name
 1      John Doe
 2      Jane Doe
```

Here is the dataset from the second table

```
tblTask
TID    Task                     EstMin    NID
1      Fix the bed              45        1
2      Clean room               30        1
3      Wipe the floor           20        1
4      Cook breakfast           45        2
5      Clean the dishes         30        2
```

The NID columns on both tables relate to them. I need a query that will generate the dataset below

```
Result dataset
NID    Name       Task            EstMin  Task               EstMin     Task             EstMin
1      John Doe   Fix the bed     45      Clean room         30         Wipe the floor   20
2      Jane Doe   Cook breakfast  45      Clean the dishes   30
```

Comment: You can start by JOINing the tables and assigning a sequence  number with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NID ORDER BY TID) AS Seq` in the SELECT list. This sequence number will drive the placement of each task in the results. Now, wrap that up in a *subquery*. In the outer query, `GROUP BY TID, Name` and perhaps `(Seq + 2) / 3` (in case you have 4 or more tasks that need to be split across result rows). Finally, you can use *conditional aggregation* to pivot the data. Something like `MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 1 THEN Task END) AS Task1` and similar for `Task2, Task3, EstMin1, EstMin2, and EstMin3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT T.NID, T.NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN S.TASK END) AS TASK1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN S.ESTMIN END) AS ESTMIN1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN S.TASK END) AS TASK2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN S.ESTMIN END) AS ESTMIN2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN S.TASK END) AS TASK3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN S.ESTMIN END) AS ESTMIN3
FROM
   (SELECT F.NID, F.NAME,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.NID ORDER BY S.TID) AS RN  
     FROM FIRST_TABLE F
     JOIN SECOND_TABLE S ON F.NID = S.NID) T
GROUP BY T.NID, T.NAME;
```

Comment: Strange. Your answer wasn't visible to me when I posted my comment. Interesting that the answers are virtually identical.

Comment: Ohh! It happens when we both are on the same speed. haha. Cheers!!